# how to use literal string type key in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
  type fruits = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'berry';
  type fruitsSeeds = Record<`${fruits}Seed`, number>;
  const mySeeds: fruitsSeeds = { appleSeed: 3, bananaSeed: 2, berrySeed: 6 };
  const myApple: fruits = 'apple';

  const myAppleSeeds = mySeeds[`${myApple}Seed`];
  //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'fruitsSeeds'.
  // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'fruitsSeeds'.ts(7053)
```

I trying to use tight type interface.
but here's some probleam to get property with literal key.
is there better way without changing literal type to string?

Comment: `const myAppleSeeds = mySeeds[\`${myApple}Seed\` as const];`

Comment: I believe you can write it is an answer

Comment: Thanks zerkms! This perfectly works for me